# link to external javascript file in a subdirectory from a web host

Tags: javascript, web-hosting

I have my index.html at the root of my web host, and my javascript file is in a directory(JavaScript) which is also at the root. How can I link my index to the js file? I did the following, but it's not working: `<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/filename.js"></script>` in the head. It works when I do the inline javascript

Comment: try to see (with Firebug for example) what URL is actually being downloaded from. Maybe the relative path or a base href are messing things up.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/file.js"></script>
```

Loads the file.js in the subdirectory "JavaScript". It'll work unless a base href is specified.

Edit: I see now that's pretty much what you had. Should work. You got full code or URL?

Comment: <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/ScrollingMessage.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1>The Website is under construction</h1>
    <form name="msgForm" action="" >
      <input type="text" name="scrollingMsg" size="25"/>
    </form>
</body>

Comment: It doesn't work for css either. It works only when all the files are at the root

Comment: here is my site: www.phathoang.info

Comment: So the server is responding that there's no such thing as http://www.phathoang.info/JavaScript/ScrollingMessage.js. You're sure it's in that folder and actually under the web root, not your home directory or whatever? If so, I would guess some server misconfiguration.

Comment: It's just working now, have no idea what happened. thanks for ur concern!